# Proof in number-theory

Tags: number-theory

Is there exist any proof for this statement?
$a^x + b^x > \left(\frac{a + b}{2}\right)^x$ for any $x > 1$.
I am interested in values between $0$ and $1$ for $a$ and $b$. I appreciate it if you provide a general proof (e.g. series) for this statement.

Thanks

Comment: What's avg(a,b)?

Comment: Average of a and b (a+b/2)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Ali I've edited your post to match what I think you're trying to achieve

Comment: I mean a general proof for this statement that the average of two or more than two numbers power of x (x>1) is less than the sum of these numbers power of x. I want to use this statement in my paper but I don't know whether any proof exist for this or not. It is a little similar to fermat's last theorem but I need this.

Comment: @Ali The stronger $\,\frac{a^x+b^x}{2} \ge \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^x\,$ for $x \gt 1$ follows from the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Definition).

Comment: @B. Mehta thanks

Comment: @dxiv thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dxiv notes in the comments, a stronger inequality is true.

First observe that $f(t) = t^x$ is a convex function for $x > 1$, $t>0$ which you can check with calculus. Then, $f(\frac{a+b}{2}) \leq \frac{1}{2} (f(a) + f(b))$, giving the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a>b$

Your equation results in 
$$a^x+b^x=S^x$$

Where $$b<S<a$$

Thus
$$b^x<S^x<a^x$$

Seeing the original equation using this, its clear the LHS is far greater than the RHS.

Because $$a^x>S^x; b^x>0$$

Comment: thanks a lot Rhys

Comment: No problem Ali, Does it make sense?

Comment: Completely, but I don't know how I can cite it in my paper, I need a good reference for solid proof.

Comment: That is actually solid enough proof. a and b are interchangeable, you can simply denote $a$ to be the larger of the two. Since $x>1$, raising $a$ and $b$ to $x$, their average, $S$, raised to $x$ will still come between $a^x$ and $b^x$. Since we know that $a^x>S^x$ and $b^x>0$, we can infer that $a^x+b^x>S^x$

Comment: Yes! I'm so thankful Rhys :)